# What is this glowing red box?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

So I'm running my guys around, and I see this glowing red box. It's doing that "closing" animation that the blue boxes do when you hover over one of your soldiers who is selectable. Any idea what's causing this?

[image: Glowing Red Box]

Comment: Does it show up anywhere you can't move them to? Or anywhere outside your sight? Or both?

Comment: It didn't move. It showed up in a console, and no where else. It stayed there regardless of which soldier I had selected. I guess it was probably just a glitch?!

Comment: My guess is, that it indicates that you can't move there. Probably you moved your mouse of that field somewhen. It is not removed due to a bug. This is just a wild-ass-guess but it sounds logical.

Comment: I had the exact same thing happen to me (I believe it was in the enemy base). The red box just stood there and never went away, although I did not try to 'undo' it by hovering my cursor over it.  I suppose this is indeed a minor bug. Didn't really _bug_ me.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The normal blue movement box becomes red when hovering over a place where your soldier can't reach.

What you are showing is a bug, where the red box "got stuck" at that place. If it really bothers you, try to save and reload the game, or just continue and disregard it.